# Jenkins - file transfer to sudo user directory in the target server

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to transfer all .sh files from one unix server to another using jenkins.

Files are getting transfer but it is coming in my unix home directory, I need to transfer it sudo user directory.

**for example**:

> - Source server name is "a" and target server name is "u"
> - we are using sell4 as sudo user in target server name
> - it should come in home directory of sell4 user

I have used the below command

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/EDB-ExtractFilefromSVN
SSH: Connecting from host [a]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [u] ...
SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [sudo scp *.sh sell4@u:/usr/app/TomcatDomain/ScoringTools_ACCDomain04/] ...
sudo: scp: command not found
SSH: EXEC: completed after 201 ms
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [u] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [1]]
Gitcolony notification failed - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid url: 
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

Can you please suggest what I am going wrong here?

**EDITS:**

Adding the shell screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command` what is that ? some plugin ?

Comment: I don't know from where it is taking this. I have not used it. I have used sudo scp command only.

Comment: paste whole Jenkins shell as it does not look like standard scp command output.

Comment: @DawidGosławski If I am correct, its [Publish over ssh plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin)

Comment: @Wolfgang You can simply add another transfer set (under the same server box) and leave all empty, only fill command to move transferred files.. But its more a workaround, then the solution. But it should work if you specify remote directory as the wanted one.

Comment: About the error message, try to fill the command as like this 
`sudo /usr/bin/scp *.sh ...` (with the full path where the `scp` is located - use `which scp` to get path)- on the source server of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah so it's some kind of plugin. It seems like you want to run local `sudo` to login to remote server user. It won't work this way. You can't open door to bathroom and expect walking into a garden.

`sudo` changes your local user to root, not remote server.

Do not use sudo with scp command but rather follow these answers:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66021/changing-user-while-scp

Comment: Probably [Publish over ssh plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin)
:)